# How can i detect from client/server side if the other side lost his net connection?

Tags: c++, winsock2, tcpsocket

I'm using Winsock2, and i made a TCP socket over IPv4.

I know how to detect if one side closed connection (checking the value of recv function), but what if a side loses its internet connection?

Anyone both the client and the server can't detect the other side has no more connection to the network (with this method).

Comment: You need to use heartbits, when the client or server stop sending them, you can assume that there is a problem on the other side

Comment: Could you explain me better? Is it something about the option KEEP_ALIVE?

Comment: Heartbeats consist in some data sent periodically between server and clients to ensure that the other side is alive. You can implement it with a simple tag message and some timer logic.

Comment: The `SO_KEEPALIVE` option enables/disables the use of TCP's own keep-alive hearbeats at the provider level outside of your application code. But if possible, it is usually best to implement your own heartbeats and timeouts in your communication protocol.

Comment: It's because SO_KEEPALIVE sends zero length packets between actual posts, producing duplicate ACKs, which might be undesirable. On long range connections, like Internet area,  that may create confusion if ACK may be duplicated or lost accidently

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you need to  learn about OSI model at least, before asking that question.
TCP, IPv4 do not have anything in common with media (Ethernet, internet), they encapsulated into it. What is that you did mean, I suppose, was a case of dropped connection (so called half-open connection). TCP uses three-way handshake process and four way  connection closure. After connection is established, if no data is sent by either side, then no packets  would cross used medium. TCP is idle protocol, on its level there is no "heartbeat" message send from client to server.

TCP was designed this way for resiliency and efficiency, allowing cables being unplugged and re-plugged. This design is also efficient, since no “polling” packets are sent across the network just to check if the connection is still exist. Why it doesn't always work in real life? Usually either because after re-initialization of connection, client side had been assigned new IP via DHCP, or server already marked that connection as timed out. How servers do that? they suppose that if client is idle too long, then connection is safe to close. Client software *usually* designed to re-establish session as soon as it is required. Some application level protocols, that require harsher restrictions on the session flow, use some kind of periodic "heartbeat" packets, also known as keep-alive packets. There are such things as ICMP protocol client or server *may* try to use, but there are limitation to that, including that of ICMP might be blocked by NAT routers or some firewalls.

There is a classic example of case when heartbeat and timeout aren't part f protocol: FTP. It is designed as two connections, one is "command channel" and one for data transfer. To not run out of  client pool, FTP server usually closes data connection if there is no commands is sent over certain time. What happens if  client asked to "GET" a large file? Server may cut out transfer before  transfer is finished. It can be solved by "passive" FTP, where it is server  side, which creates data connection in response to login from client. That might be not possible, if client can't receive connection, being behind router. Other solution was that client periodically sends some "dummy" command that doesn't cause much of traffic, for example "PWD" (get current folder).

There is much written on topic of half-open connection, you should decide on your own, which design you find preferable.

Comment: What if i teoretically know all those things? I know how OSI model works, i know how TCP works. I asked a way to CODE this situation. I need something to handle the half-open connection. How can i do this in C++ using Winsock2? I just can't figure out how to implement this. I need to detect on server side when the client drop his connection, cause i want to close the socket and exit from my program.

Comment: Pretty much you need to draft what kind of protocol you will use between client and server , involving the half-open state detection, then implement it. There is no set in stone workflows or patterns for that, especially if you're using pure API instead of some libraries. There are examples around net, you should research them

Comment: @Serusar There is  rarely used option for socket, as part of protocol https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee470551(v=vs.85).aspx